# Designing a collapsible responsive navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, responsive-design

I've been having some difficulty customizing a responsive navigation jQuery plugin called [slimMenu](http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/). I have set up a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/Nmh9Z/). Ultimately, I'd like to create a responsive header in which the h1 "logo" is floated to the left of a container (i.e. header), and the navigation links are floated to the right. Upon triggering the collapsed menu-- here I've set a breakpoint of 600px in the plugin initialization:

```
$('ul.slimmenu').slimmenu({
    resizeWidth: '600'
});
```

which you can see by changing the width of the "results" pane in jsFiddle-- I'd like the dropdown list items to fill the viewport at 100% width as I've illustrated in this diagram:

[image: responsive nav menu diagram]

This plugin is set to show text next to the hamburger menu icon when triggered-- in this case it's "Menu"-- but I'd like no text to be shown and just have the "Logo" header persist floated at left. I'm suspecting that problem lies in floating the header & nav elements and perhaps they need to be positioned within a container and make media-query-targeted adjustments to the list items (?) but my attempts in this vein have not worked.

Thanks for any assistance here. I'll gladly buy anyone a coffee for anyone who finds a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can specify what the label text is in the slimMenu options. Set it to this:

```
$('ul.slimmenu').slimmenu(
{
    resizeWidth: '600',
    collapserTitle: '',
    easingEffect:'easeInOutQuint',
    animSpeed:'medium',
    indentChildren: true,
    childrenIndenter: '&raquo;'
});
```

and it should give you what you're looking for.

Edit:
And to address the 100% width that I neglected in the original answer you could do this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        width:100%;
    }
    h1 {
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 100;
    } 
}
```

where the max-width is set to the same width as the 'resizeWidth' option in slimMenu.

Also, it would probably benefit you to apply a class or ID to both the nav and h1 elements to make sure you're not hitting all of your h1s with that media query.

Comment: Thanks for the response rwaymouth but that doesn't address the overall layout issue as far as the drop down items filling the viewport width as I've demonstrated in the diagram.

Comment: Thanks rwaymouth-- we're getting closer :) I've updated the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/Nmh9Z/18/). While the collapsed menu is working perfectly, now the issue is with the uncollapsed state, as the navigation is floating left and overlapping with the header. I guess the real challenge is keeping the nav floated right in the "regular" state and filling 100% width-- beneath the header-- in the "collapsed" state. Any further ideas?

Comment: From looking at the jsFiddle it looks like the issue is your media query is set at 768px and the menu breakpoint is set at 600px, which gives you the overlap when the screen is between 600px and 768px. If you change the 'resizeWidth' option to 768px it looks like everything works as it should.